# What is "automatic movie mode"

Tags: ios, video

One of the new features listed in the iOS 6 release notes is

- automatic movie mode for improved video sound quality

What does this feature do?

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours, it's not explained anywhere.  My guess is it's an audio level balancer to louden quiet sounds, and limit loud noises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new feature analyses the video that you are currently watching and it adjusts the Equalizer automatically so that the sound quality is optimal for the current movie scene.

Anyway many people think it's intrusive and that it actually decreases sounds quality. Others like it.
It's up to you I think.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it, or at least somehow compare what it sounds like without it?

Comment: I don't think so. It's a new feature and it's embedded into the operating system and it's constantly on. 
Basically - it's made to be there without you noticing it.

As far as I know there are people who don't like it and have taken the issue with Apple.